# Custom TreeView loses its styling when adding IsExpanded

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a custom treeview in my XAML, which again has custom treeview items.

Problem: when I try to use the "IsExpanded" on my custom item, this will override the entire style of the treeview. Meaning I lose my style on the entire tree.

In short my code looks like:

```
<customControl:CustomTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <customControl:CustomTreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="customControls:CustomTreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsNodeExpanded}"/>
        </Style TargetType="customControls:CustomTreeViewItem">
    </customControl:CustomTreeView.Resources>
</customControl:CustomTreeView>
```

Hence my question: is it possible to reach/use property "IsExpanded" on tree view item without messing up the entire custom style on the treeview? Like: inherit property "IsExpanded" from `TreeViewItem` or `CustomTreeViewItem`, but keep style from `CustomTreeView`.

Worth mentioning that the binding on "IsExpanded" works fine, the only issue is the styling disappearing... :/